# Pattern matching in html

Tags: javascript, html, pattern-matching

I am making a html script by which i have to open multiple tabs. 
Here is a script for it.

`<body>
    <html>
    <a onclick="window.open(&quot;8_Aug_2013.timing_nos.html/&quot;);window.open(&quot;newdate.html/&quot;)"href="new.html/" target="_blank">Sheets</a>
    </body>
    </html>`

I need to match the pattern with date (i.e. 8_Aug_2013,9_Aug_2013 & so on). So that the tab will open by itself with all sheets with *_Aug_2013.
So can anybody help me with this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot open multiple tabs.**
There's no concept of tab in standard DOM.Its more of a browser thing

I have tried this and there is no way you can do this.

However,the nearest you can come is use these properties in the same function `window.location.href` which opens in the same tab and  `window.open` which opens in a new tab.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jx433/

Comment: Hi VAGABOND, Thanks for your reply. I am new to HTML so i dont know much about it in coding. All i have to do by this code is i have to open all HTML pages with pattern starting from *_AUG_2013.html as i am saving some html files named as 7_AUG_2013,8_AUG_2013,9_AUG_2013 & so on.

Comment: dont waste your time in doing this.Its certainly not possible.good luck with your project.Accept the answer if you think its worthy!!